# getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_icon) obsoleto, como prosseguir

Tags: java, bitmap

Olá, estou com problemas com o fato de que o `getDrawable` está obsoleto. Por gentileza, como eu posso converter o meu código para que ele possa estar atualizado? Agradeço desde já!

```
int height = 100;
    int width = 100;
    BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.guardian_ico);
    Bitmap b=bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
    Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mesmo sua pergunta não sendo muito objetiva eu deduzo pela sintaxe que você esteja programando para Android com a linguagem Java utilizando Android Studio. Utilize a biblioteca Picasso para a manipulação de imagens. Ela é de fácil integração e super fácil de utilizar. Segue o link para a Doc de como implementar e como utilizar:
http://square.github.io/picasso/